# How to SELECT n columns and a SUM, while only grouping by some of the non-aggregate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL fundamentals may be a bit off on this one, but I'd appreciate any help.

As the question states I am attempting to do something like the following (not using Concat() because I'm stuck with SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
SELECT name, phone, (id1+'-'+id2+'-'+id3) as id
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN code IN ('00','01','02','03','04','05') 
       THEN expenses ELSE 0 END) AS sum_expenses
FROM random_table
GROUP BY id1, id2, id3
```

This query will throw an error because name and phone are not being grouped. I am looking for a solution where I can group the summed expenses by their id while retaining name and phone as non-aggregate, non-grouped columns as they are essential fields to keep for each id row. I have been unable to find a clear answer on StackOverflow just yet.

Solutions I have considered in trying to resolve this issue but am unsure are feasible (/even applicable): 1) Subquerying the Sum within the Select statement; 2) Using Common Table Expressions to separate the Sum from the main query, 3) Creating a separate table for the id field and Sum and then joining it back in using id as the common field.

**Please note, the reason for not including name and phone in the GROUP By is that I need to group my data by unique id rows**

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `GROUP BY id1, id2, id3, name, phone`?

Comment: The above is just a basic example; there are many more fields some of which have multiple values per id row. I need to group my data by unique id rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windowed functions, cross apply, common table expressions are all viable options.

Here is an example using common table expressions and cross apply.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    id3,
    (id1 + '-' + id2 + '-' + id3) AS id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN code IN ('00','01','02','03','04','05') THEN expenses ELSE 0 END) AS sum_expenses
  FROM random_table
  GROUP BY id1, id2, id3
)

SELECT
  ca.name,
  ca.phone,
  cte.id,
  cte.sum_expenses
FROM CTE AS cte
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1
    name,
    phone
  FROM random_table AS rt
  WHERE rt.id1 = cte.id1
    AND rt.id2 = cte.id2
    AND rt.id3 = cte.id3
) AS ca
```

Comment: Thank you; this is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't heard of CROSS APPLY before.

Answer (score 0):

The columns mentioned in the group by clause would be unique in your output.

I suggest you have a look at the windowing functions.

Eg:

```
select name,phone,(id1+'-'+id2+'-'+id3) as id
       ,sum(CASE WHEN code IN ('00','01','02','03','04','05') 
                 THEN expenses 
                 ELSE 0 
             END) over(partition by id1, id2, id3) as summed_by_id
from random_table
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into windowing functions as well for future queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
SELECT name, phone, (id1+'-'+id2+'-'+id3) as id
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN code IN ('00','01','02','03','04','05') 
       THEN expenses ELSE 0 END) over (partition by id1, id2, id3) AS sum_expenses
FROM random_table
```